# selecting features having area in a specific range

Tags: google-earth-engine, vector, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter

I have converted the image to vector, now I need to select area features which are less than 5sqkm and greater than 0.5sqkm. following is the code but I'm getting an error, please help me with the code.

```js
// Add area property to dissolved features(non water).
var addArea = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({areaSqKm: feature.geometry().area(1).divide(10e6)});
};
var areaAdded = vector.map(addArea);

    
// Print the first feature of the dissolved and area-added feature collection.
print('First feature:', areaAdded.first());
    
// Add the dissolved and area-added feature collection to the map.
Map.addLayer(areaAdded, {color:'blue'}, 'Dissolved and Area-Added Features');
    
////////////////FILTER AREA////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var Area = areaAdded.filter(ee.Filter.lt('areaSqKm', 5).and(ee.Filter.gt('areaSqKm',0.05)));
Map.addLayer(Area,{},"Area in range")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ee.Filter.lt` and `ee.Filter.gt` filters must be arguments of `ee.Filter.and`, take a look to the [`ee.Filter.and`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-filter-and) documentation.

The correct way:

```
var Area = areaAdded.filter(ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.lt('areaSqKm', 5), ee.Filter.gt('areaSqKm',0.05)));
```

Comment: Thank you, earlier I wasn't able to comment.